# Hint for this equicontinuity/bounded question

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

> Let $X$ be a compact metric space. Prove that an equicontinuous subset
>   of $C(X)$ is uniformly bounded if it is pointwise bounded.

I'm not looking for the answer. I know all the relevant definitions but I'd like a hint as to what $X$ being compact implies.

Comment: As a way to understand why you need compactness, can you create a counterexample if compactness is lacking?

Comment: On $\mathbb{R}$, the one-member family consisting of $f(x)=x$ works. Or the family consisting of $f(x)=ax$ for all $|a|\leq 100$.

Comment: @user25959: I was addressing that to the original questioner, not to the general public.

Answer (score 1):

We'll denote members of the equicontinuous family by $f_\alpha$.

Let $M_x >0$ satisfy $|f_\alpha(x)|< M_x$ for all $\alpha$ (which exists because of the pointwise bound).

Now fix $x$ in $X$. *Equicontinuity* implies there is some $\delta$ such that $d(x,y)< \delta \implies |f_\alpha(y)| < M_{x} + 1$.

Consider the set $B_x = B(x,\delta)$. It is (and here's the hint) an open set containing $x$.

Comment: Why is $B_x$ an open set? Maybe better to let $B_x=B(x,\delta)$?

Comment: Thank you for the comment. It is open but that would require another equicontinuity argument. I changed it.

Comment: @user25959 Thanks. But aren't balls always open? Why does this hinge on $X$ being compact?

Comment: Definition of compactness: cover $X$ with the $B_x$. Then extract a finite subcover.

Comment: This is explicitly *not* addressing the OP. It's giving the solution, not probing for why compactness is required.

Comment: I don't think I gave the solution, in particular the uniform bound is still left to be found. However I addressed an implication of compactness. OP did not ask why it is required, or else just providing counterexamples is sufficient.

Comment: @user25959 Would the open cover be $B(x_1\ \delta_{x_1})\cup B(x_2,\ \delta_{x_2})\cup...$ where $x_1, x_2, \ldots\in X$? We then take a finite subcover and use the maximum value of $M_x+1$ as the upper bound for $f_\alpha(y)$ -- is that correct? What if $X$ has an uncountable number of elements?

Comment: That's what I was thinking @Thomas. Even though $X$ is infinite, every $y$ can be placed into some $B(x_i,\delta_{x_i})$ and hence by the construction of $\delta_{x_i}$, etc... 

If $X$ were finite then the uniform bound would come out almost immediately (can you think why). Compactness when $X$ is infinite makes the argument almost the same argument as in the finite case.

Comment: @user25959 My question is, if $X$ was uncountable, like $X=[a, b]$, what would I take $x_1, x_2, \ldots$ to be?

Comment: Afaik there's no issue here arising from uncountability/countability. The main difference is between finite and infinite. Even if it's uncountable, a compact $X$ still fits into finitely many open balls $B_{x_i}$. You don't have to explicitly name them - they exist by definition of compactness: every open cover has a finite subcover.

Comment: @user25959 I absolutely agree that every open cover has a finite subcover. But one must first have an open cover in order to extract a finite subcover. I just don't know what one would take the open cover to be even in the simple case of $X=[a, b]$.

Comment: Notice how we constructed $B_x$ using an arbitrary $x$. Then the open cover is $\{B_x\}$ for all x.